# UUID's when changing hardware

Tags: linux, hardware, uuid

My question is this...

In /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1 there is a UUID to identify the on-board network interface.

I also notice now that some partitions in fstab are also identified by a UUID.

If I remove the hard drives from this server and put them into a new "identical" server, will everything still work as expected?

I doubt there would be an issue with the HDD's, as the UUID's will move with them  - but will there be some sort of mismatch on the network UUIDs, as the hardware has changed?

It stands to reason that if I have a faulty system board, I will want to move the storage into a spare server and have everything working again quickly.

Are the network interface UUID's only used by Network Manager? I have that disabled, so perhaps it's a good idea to simply remove the UUID entry from the config file anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**If I remove the hard drives from this server and put them into a new "identical" server, will everything still work as expected?**

First the `/etc/fstab`. These are UUID numbers for drive partitions. See [info](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab).

If you use the very same drive in another machine the UUID numbers for the partitions will be the same. Assuming that all referenced partitions are on the single HD that was moved. IF `/etc/fsab` refers to partitions on another HD, they would not be valid any more unless that drive is moved to the new machine also.

**"network UUID..."**

Do you mean the MAC address of the network cards? Its is possible for an interface to have a UUID assigned to it, but more than likely its the MAC address you are questioning.

The MAC address *should* be unique for each NIC. If you move the network card to the new machine the MAC would be the same, but not necessarily the name.

If the NIC was an on-board it will NOT be the same.

If you have physical access to the new machine, I recommend removing all network interfaces and letting the system setup the "new" NIC on the new machine.

Yes, you will need to re assign, setup the network again with the new info.

If your network interfaces have a name assigned to them like `eth0` or `mylocal`, you could not remove them but change what physical NIC belongs to what name.

Comment: Not mac addresses. RHEL7 has UUID's within the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/[interface] file.
There's no need to set up the network again. I will be removing the hdd's from one identical machine and putting them into another.

Comment: What about the NICs? IF onboard the OS will see the new machine NIC as a new device. Looking into RHEL7 NICs...

Comment: If the interface name is something like `eth0` or `enp3s0` in the ` /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/[interface]` path, you could just assign the new NIC the same name used on old hardware...

Comment: Are you sure the nic will be seen as a new device? Won't the first nic simply be considered "eno1"? Are you suggesting it will be seen as different due to the UUID?
What procedure would you need to carry out if you simply replaced the system board with a new identical one? This is essentially what I'm doing here.
Also, the part of my question concerning network manager. If the UUID is only used by network manager, can I simply remove the entry from the config file - as I have NM disabled?